# Show another object's value in another object, JSON File

Tags: javascript, json

There must be a way around this but I don't remember.

I need to read the value of another object in the same json file

For ex:

```
{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "fullName" : "{firstName} {lastName}" // I need to show two values here, how can I do that?
}
```

I don't need any js functions just this should be inside the JSON file

Comment: Can you provide some code you tried?

Comment: Either the code that creates the JSON file should put the fullName there, or the code that reads it should automatically add this field

Comment: This is a static file, for example I need something like this

{
     "firstName": "John",
     "lastName": "Smith",
     "welcomeMessage" : "{firstName} {lastName} Welcome Home"
}

Comment: I'm using AngularJS (angular-translate),   <span translate="fullName"></span>

Comment: It looks like angular-translate supports custom loaders. So you could fetch the JSON file, add the `fullName` property, and then return the updated object to angular-translate

Comment: Yes I know but I want to do this in json file, is there such a possibility?

Comment: I highly doubt so. There seem to be [JSON references](https://json-spec.readthedocs.io/reference.html), but I highly doubt that your json parser supports these. Again, you could preprocess the JSON file and modify it before the client fetches it (e.g. server side, in a CI pipeline build, precommit hook, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a fairly simple data format. It does not have any features that allow one property to reference anything.

You could build your own syntax layer on top of JSON and do additional processing. Perhaps using [a reviver function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter) or by post-processing the parsed object. The latter would likely be easier as you wouldn't have the risk of trying to reference a property that hasn't been parsed yet.

You could also look for an existing data format which suits your needs better than JSON. [OmegaConf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.2_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation) supports variable interpolation and is based on YML (which fulfils a similar niche to JSON) although it is a Python library rather than a JS one. There may be an existing JS library that suits your needs.